# Any hint to simplify this POST? (Java)

Tags: java, post, jax-rs, crud

I implemented this POST operation in Jax-RS and it is working fine, however I am sure I can send the body in other way somehow. Any hint to simplify it? (**By receiving an object for instance?**)

Thanks!

```
@POST
@Path("updateUser/{name}/{surname}/{address}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response updateUser(@FormParam("user") String name,
          @FormParam("surname") String surname,
          @FormParam("address") String address) throws UnknownHostException {
          User user;
          user = new CorporateUser(name, surname, address); 
          usersService.updateUser(user);
          return Response.ok(user).build();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a JSON provider like [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) to your project.

```
@POST
@Path("updateUser")
@Consumes(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces(value = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response updateUser(NewCorporateUserRequest req) throws UnknownHostException {
      User user;
      user = new CorporateUser(req.getName(), req.getSurname(), req.getAddress()); 
      usersService.updateUser(user);
      return Response.ok().entity(user).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
}

public class NewCorporateUserRequest implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String address;

    ... Getters and Setters.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass json string of object by using @consumes annotaion.

```
  @POST
  @Path("/updateUser")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response updateUser(User bean) {
    usersService.updateUser(user);
          return Response.ok(user).build();
  }
```